# How can I create a MS 2010 document with sections (drop down) pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I have a requirement to create a major project template document with repeating content controls and sections that need to be hidden (or expandable).

Sections represent what would normally be standalone documents themselves but I want to harness the power of repeating content controls, but be able to hide or toggle the remaining sections until they are needed. 
Ideally when the user opens this template document for the first time the document would look like this.

**Section 1**

Heading 1

Body content 1

Heading 2

Body content 2

Heading 3

Body content 3

**Section 2** [expandable section]

**Section 3** [expandable section]

**Section 4** [expandable section]

**Section 5** [expandable section]

If once Section 1 is complete and approved, When the user comes back to the document to add Section 2 content they would click on Section 2 and it would expand. It would already have some nominated fields populated from Section 1. Thus the expanded section may look like this:

**Section 1**

Heading 1

Body content 1

Heading 2

Body content 2

Heading 3

Body content 3

**Section 2** [expanded]

Heading 2

Body content 1 (repeating content control from section 1)

Heading 2

Body content 2

Heading 3

Body content 2 (repeating content control from section 1)

**Section 3** [expandable section]

**Section 4** [expandable section]

**Section 5** [expandable section]

Section 3 and onwards would have repeating content controls fields again from the documents before them.

Is this function possible on MS Word 2010?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collapse-or-expand-parts-of-a-document-701786e0-95e2-40bf-bfe5-f0233cd3520c) Because this functionality was apparently only added in Word 2013...

Comment: Yes. I believe so. But the problem is, I don't have MS 2010 :(

Comment: You mean don't have MS 2013, right? Because your question says you have 2010. In which case the answer is no, this function is not possible in MS 2010, AFAIK...sorry

Comment: Actually, I just found how to do it. It involves Visual Basic but it now works. http://www.wikihow.com/Expand-and-Collapse-in-Microsoft-Word

Comment: Not exactly the same, but if it works for your needs, great!